# How to import all the scss files in parent folder

Tags: sass

I have following imports in my "themes.scss" files

```
@import "components/modal";
@import "components/button";
@import "components/grid";
@import "components/calendar";
@import "components/popover";
@import "components/tab";
@import "components/icon";
```

I have tried following way to import all the ".scss" files at one time:

```
@import "components/*"
```

Unfortunately it's not working (in windows 8), I am getting an error while scss to css compilation.

```
Syntax error: It's not clear which file to import for '@import "components/*"'.
              Candidates:
                components/_modal.scss
                components/_button.scss
                components/_grid.scss
                components/_calendar.scss
                .
                .
              Please delete or rename all but one of these files.
        on line 8 of C:\component\theme.scss
  Use --trace for backtrace.
```

Is there any way through which I can convert all the scss files by just importing parent folder instead of each individual scss file?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: @cimmanon Answer provided in the previously asked question wasn't working..  (Is it possible to import a whole directory in sass using @import? )

Comment: Which answer doesn't work?

Comment: I tried both ways by referring the originally answered question, none of them worked:  i) @import "foo/*"     // import all the files in the foo folder   ii)@import "bar/**/*"  // import all the files in the bar tree

Comment: Did you skip over the fact that it only works if you're using Ruby-on-Rails or if you're using the sass-globbing extension?

Comment: I am looking for a generic solution without that condition (already checked the question you've mentioned before posting this).   So far didn't found any solution, so thought of posting the question on SO.